# How do you interpret/feedback IRT theta scores?

Tags: item-response-theory

In classical test theory (CTT), we would say something like:
"Your score is higher than 80% of people in the normgroup."

In item response theory (IRT), how do we interpret/feedback a theta score of 0.85?
I [know](http://jonathantemplin.com/files/irt/irt11icpsr/irt11icpsr_lecture02.pdf) that it is supposed to be 'item-referenced' as opposed to be 'norm-referenced', but I am unsure how to put this to practice.

You are able to solve tasks that are so difficult that only 20% of others can?

Comment: Could you expand "CTT". IRT is a family of models, so i is important to say which models you consider (binary, 2-parameter Rasch model?).

Comment: I am using a 2 parameter model now. Is the interpretation of theta that different depending upon the number of parameters in the model?

Comment: And what is the most important - what is the distribution of thetas? Typically it's Gaussian (mean 0 std 1, or something different?) but may be something different (fixed or fitted to the data).

Comment: @PiotrMigdal CTT is [classical test theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_test_theory) from psychometrics.

Answer (score 3):

As @user136371 says, item response theory (IRT) theta scores estimates $\hat\theta$ can be interpreted as standardized z-scores when the latent variable mean $\mu_\theta$ and standard deviation $\sigma_\theta$ are fixed to 0 and 1 respectively. Remember that this is only the case when an estimation method such as the marginal maximum likelihood (MML) is used.

Additionally, a strength of IRT methods is that reliability is not fixed across $\theta$, so $SE(\hat\theta)$ should be used in conjunction with $\hat\theta$ when interpreting $\hat\theta$ as standardized z-scores.

Finally, see a previous answer of mine [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/585117/is-it-acceptable-common-practice-to-report-irt-theta-scores-as-a-percentile/591277#591277) that goes into the z-score interpretation of IRT theta scores in more detail.

Comment: I understand the statistical interpretation. What I would like to know is how to link back the Theta score to the observable performance. Theta 1 would mean that 68% of users are unable to solve tasks that are as difficult as this user can?

Comment: Yes, @SunWuKung, that is a correct interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

theta is a standardized z-score. theta of 0 = mean of your latent trait, SD = 1. theta of 0.85 means nearly 1 standard deviation above the mean.